# When to choose non-transactional database engine?

Tags: database, transactions

I discovered that there exist some relational database engines that are non-transactional. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_engine. MySQL, in particular, supports the MyISAM engine and used to use it as default. What are the advantages of a non-transactional engine over a transactional one - when would you choose to use it?

Comment: Speed, potentially. But I wouldn't use a non-ACID DB, unless for some special-purpose application where concurrency was never an issue.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706717/7154924d